# Call to Hibernate save leads to hung thread

Tags: spring, hibernate, save

We are using Hibernate and Spring using DAO pattern where the application calls a separate DAO class for every database call. We use SQL Server as our database.

For some time we are seeing that a save call to the Hibernate just leads to a hung thread and we are clueless about this. The same code works in a different environment (separate server, separate database server but same version).

We are using Hibernate 4.3.10 and nothing has changed in the application since 2 years.

What could be going wrong?

The code for the class which calls the save is pasted below. BusinessAlerts is just a POJO class.

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void persistBusinessAlert(BusinessAlerts businessAlert) throws DAOException {
    if (businessAlert == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        currentSession().save(businessAlert);
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        throw new DAOException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

We have identified the thread stack trace but I am unable to post it here fully.

The Hibernate properties for the DB are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

            <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="priceTransactionManager" />

            <bean class="mro.util.CryptoPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
                           <property name="location" value="common_db.properties" />
            </bean>

            <bean id="priceDataSource" destroy-method="close"
                           class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
                <property name="url" value="${alert.db.url}" />
                <property name="username" value="${alert.db.username}" />
                <property name="password" value="${alert.db.password}" />
            </bean>

            <bean id="priceSessionFactory"
                           class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="priceDataSource" />
                <property name="annotatedClasses">
                    <list>
                        <value>BusinessAlerts</value>
                        <value>Executions</value>
                        <value>AlertCodes</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
                <property name="hibernateProperties">
                    <props>
                        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    </props>
                </property>
            </bean>

            <bean id="priceTransactionManager"
                           class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
                <property name="sessionFactory" ref="priceSessionFactory" />
            </bean>
</beans>
```

`currentSession()` is a Hibernate call and this is what comes up when we find more about it:

```
protected final org.hibernate.Session currentSession() throws org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException;
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokevirtual org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSessionFactory() : org.hibernate.SessionFactory [10]
     4  invokeinterface org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() : org.hibernate.Session [11] [nargs: 1]
     9  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 129]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.HibernateDaoSupport
```

Comment: Stack trace: 
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1981)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:6310)
    - locked com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader@611ade60

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:7545)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:465)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:409)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)
    - locked java.lang.Object@141d2863

Comment: What does the `currentSession` method do. Also your `DAOException` isn't a runtime exception and thus will not rollback transactions (it isn't configured as such). Which could lead to connection leaks. So please add the `currentSession()` implementation as well as some configuration for hibnernate and the database.

Comment: @M.Deinum, currentSession() is  a Hibernate call. 

protected final org.hibernate.Session currentSession() throws org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException;
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokevirtual org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSessionFactory() : org.hibernate.SessionFactory [10]
     4  invokeinterface org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() : org.hibernate.Session [11] [nargs: 1]
     9  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 129]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 typ

Comment: No it isn't.  Not in this instance, it is a regular method that does something. What does the method do. Also add your hibernate configuration to the question. And please don't add code/xml/stacktraces as comments. Instead edit your question and add information to the question. The currently added stack trace and (decompiled code) is totally unreadable.

Comment: Sorry about the mangled code in the edit but is the assembly thing that I see when finding details about currentSession() - It is a Hibernate call.

Comment: It is a local method call which eventually delegates to Hibernate. It by itself isn't an hibernate call. Nonetheless your hibernate config appears to be right. That being said a hanging call to `save` isn't the issue but rather a symptom. Make sure that in your code you aren't working with a JDBC Connection directly, if you do make sure to close it. Also I would switch to a better Connection Pool like HikariCP instead of Commons DBCP and appropriatly configure idle connection detection and connection cleanup.

Comment: Additionally, you don't have an accidental `hibernate.properties` which contains further configuration?

Comment: Hi @VikashJain. What did you endup doing? Experiencing the same issue here.

Comment: Hello @javadev, we realized that it was not a Hibernate issue - that was just the symptom. The DB tables were locked so the thread on the update call was blocked and never proceeded ahead, giving us an impression that the thread is waiting and not returning back.